# Multiple iterators in "for", "lfor", etc. with something like "dct.items()"

Tags: hy

How could I convert the following to `hy`?

```py
dct = { 1:2, 3:4 }
print([i*j for i, j in dct.items()])
# => [2, 12]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm puzzled by your title, since there's only one iteration clause in your example, but anyway, here's a literal Hy translation:

```
(setv dct {1 2  3 4})
(print (lfor  [i j] (.items dct)  (* i j)))
; => [2, 12]
```

But you could also do this with the shadow multiplication operator:

```
(import  hy.pyops *)
(setv dct {1 2  3 4})
(print #* (map * (.keys dct) (.values dct)))
; => 2 12
```

Comment: Confirmed and accepted; however, I meant that "i" and "j" are the iterators. What are they called if not so?

Comment: @ShadowRylander I would call them "iteration variables" or "loop variables" or something like that. "Iterator" refers to the object that Python calls `.__next__()` on inside a loop: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator

Comment: Ah, right; I'd forgotten. Thanks!